# Bootstrap 3 Collapsible panel in not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am exactly following the documentation of Bootstrap 3 [collapse events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events) side. but still , Browser gives me `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` in Console , and panel does not change its glyphicon class , now problem was just about changing glyphicon  class with me but , when i copied code to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zulqurnain/v95334q0/) , now the panel is not even collapsing on it , i don't know what's going on any help?

**Updated:**

- Problem about jsfiddle was adding jquery lib , solved by @RGS updated fiddle is jsfiddle.net/v95334q0/1

Comment: You need to add jquery library reference in fiddle. Check the link https://jsfiddle.net/v95334q0/1/

Comment: Wups , sorry thank for solving problem about jsfiddle , now what about actual one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to raise click event for collapsible div id.

```
$(function() {
 $('#collapse-prob-single').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
   $(".glyphicon").addClass('glyphicon-collapse-up').removeClass('glyphicon-collapse-down');
 });
 $('#collapse-prob-single').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
   $(".glyphicon").addClass('glyphicon-collapse-down').removeClass('glyphicon-collapse-up');
 });
});
```

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/v95334q0/5/

Comment: Thanks , but why we can't use classes as `hidden.bs.collapse` as given in documentation

Comment: it have one problem , one first click it don't change glyphicon , on second click it does

Comment: @Mr.Z, You need to raise click event to collapsible div id. Check my updated demo.